# Using Googlenet and Alexnet Model is not giving accuracy on the Cat vs Dog dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, computer-vision

I am starting to learn Convolutional Neural Networks and have designed the famous MNIST and fashion-MNIST models and obtained good accuracy.
But then I moved to another trivial dataset that is cat vs. Dog dataset from Kaggle, but after applying all my concepts, I learned from Stanford lectures and Andrew ng lectures I was only able to get 80% accuracy. So, I decided to try the GoogleNet and Alexnet, but these model were not able to give me accuracy anything above 50% on 6 epochs.

I wanted to know whether the GoogleNet and ImageNet are designed for 1000 categories output and won't work on 2 categories output?

While making my own model I obtained an accuracy of 80%. I expected the famous GoogleNet model to give me more accuracy, but that's not the case.

Below is the GoogleNet model that I am using:

```
data=[]
labels=[]
for i in range(0,12499):
    img=cv2.imread("train/cat."+str(i)+".jpg")
    res = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    data.append(res)
    labels.append(0);
    img2=cv2.imread("train/dog."+str(i)+".jpg")
    res2 = cv2.resize(img2, dsize=(224,224),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    data.append(res2)
    labels.append(1);
train_data, test_data,train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(data,
                                                labels,
                                                test_size=0.2,
                                                random_state=42)
model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu', input_shape= 
(224,224,3)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(256,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(256,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dense(4096,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001), 
loss='sparse_categorical_c rossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=train_data,y=train_labels,batch_size=32,epochs=10,
validation_data=(test_data,test_labels))
```

The expected accuracy of the above google model should be more than 50%, but it's ranging between 50% and 51% after 6 epochs.

p.s I changed the last dense layer to 2 instead of 1000, and I am using Keras API for tensor flow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share rest of the code? The shared piece looks OK, it's likely the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the answer now it contains the full code.

Comment: Where do you encode your labels? You have softmax output with 2 dimensions but your Y column only has 1 dimension.

Comment: You are training this architecture from the scratch in this example BTW. What you would do in this case is to get the pretrained network to apply transfer learning for your dataset.

Comment: @SıddıkAçıl Labels are encoded in the very beginning in the code. Also, transfer learning is of little use, as OP troubleshoots rather basic problem: the network does not learn. 

Next steps: Replace "accuracy" with "sparse_categorical_accuracy" and change learning rate to e.g. 0.1. Also, let us know which accuracy (train / test) you are reporting and how loss changes, assuming first advice does not do the trick.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I was talking about the training and validation loss both of which were raning between 0.5 and 0.51.Now, i have applied the changes that you proposed but still not difference.I have attached a screen shot.[link]https://ibb.co/BfShHv5

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a bit with this earlier as well.I didn't try it yet on googlenet but I tried it on Alexnet. On Alexnet I managed to get relatively ok results (83%) for cats vs dogs after following closely to the paper. Few things you may want to do:

1. If you refer to the CS231n notes from Fei Fei Li
   http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture9.pdf
        On slide 10, you will notice that the input layer should be 227 by 227 instead. They also provided the mathematical justification
   why it is so.
2. I started to try and follow other items closely to the original
   paper here:
   https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf
        These included:

   - As in the paper section 3.3, adding a normalization layer at the end of the first two max pooling layers. Keras has stopped supporting LRN but I added batch normalization and it works. (I ran an experiment of a model with batch normalization and without. The accuracy difference is 82% versus 62%
   - As in the paper section 4.2, I added two dropout layers (0.5) at the end of the two fully connected layers.
   - As in the paper section 5, I changed my batches to 128, SGD momentum of 0.9 and weight decay of 0.0005
3. As pointed above in one of the comments from your original question,
   my final layer was also a single dimension with sigmoid function.

Training for 20 epochs gave me a 83% accuracy. In the original paper, they included data augmentation but I did not include it in my implementation.

Keras has a modified googlenet example. It is modified from the Xecption architecture, I believe one of the derivatives of the inception architecture.
https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/

I have tried it and after running for 15 epochs, accuracy is about 90%

Hope this helps.